# Page Life cycle, dealing with dependant controls

Tags: usability, forms, user-behavior

I have a web form, with two `typeaheads`:

- Customer Typeahead
- Item Typeahead

The user can select only 1 Customer  and can add multiple Items to the form, via an `asp gridview control` and a `bootstrap modal`.I load the item `typeahead` based on customer information provided by the customer `typeahead`. So if the user changes the customer at any point, i must clear the grid, as item details(Price) will change.

**My problem:**

How do i control this user behavior? How do i communicate to the user that this is how the form behaves, so as to avoid confusion and frustration.

**My thoughts:**

**Solution 1**

- Load the form with only the customer `typehead` visible
- Once customer is selected, show grid control and lock down customer typeahead

> So if the user needs to change the customer, i must either provide a change customer button to clear all data(`grid` and customer `typeahead`), OR the user needs to refresh the page completely.

**Solution 2**

- Allow the user to change customer at any point in page life cycle
- When customer is changed (clear grid details and force the user to enter items again)

I hope i made my problem clear, unambiguous and not opinion based. I can provide screen shots if required.

**These are the screen shots:**

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: screenshots would help. so you're saying that if the user changes the customer, they lose all the items in the form? Could you add an warning to the page when the user attempts to switch customer, warning them of the consequences, then allow them to proceed or cancel?

Comment: @Midas. The thing is my item prices are linked to customers via pricegroups assigned to each customer. Thus, when the customer changes, all added items must be removed, as the price for those items will not be correct.

Comment: @Midas, interesting suggestion though. Add it as an answer i will mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you have a `typeahead` control or not is purely anecdotal for your question.

You don't need to (and furthermore, **shouldn't**) clear all. Instead, you should **UPDATE** form info based on the new client's variable.

Since as you say, this field controls the price fields, then a simple update of the price fields should suffice. Like so:

```
if $client --> $clientgroup1 --> return price 1
else if $client --> $clientgroup2 --> return price 2
else if $client --> $clientgroup3 --> return price 3
else --> return price 4
```

This way you save the user some painful process. Just imagine you do some tedious form and then you realize you have only one mistake, and when you try to solve it... everything disappears! If I was the user, I'd hate any program or app that provides such a destructive behavior.

And while **warnings are necessary**, this doesn't mean your problem is solved, because you have this situation: you made a mistake, you KNOW you did it and you want to solve it. And then you show the user a warning like

> **if you do this, the world will fall apart**

*oh, OK, I don't want to do that, but... how are you going to help me solve the issue? Should I leave an error to avoid this big problem to the world?*

**And there yo have your answer:** you need to provide a solution, not to multiply the errors. Thus... **update the fields** and that's it, no weird messages, no reinventing the wheel, just plain and simple solutions